# Form send data but don't up files to server

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm working with a form that contains personal data and I want to up a photo to my remote server.
At first time I tried to up the file using the next code:

up_file.php

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $file = $_FILES["img"]["name"];
    $file_remote = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];


if ($file){
    if(strstr($file,".jpg")||strstr($file,".jpeg")||strstr($file,".png")){
        $destino = "/absolute/route/directory/".$file;
        if(move_uploaded_file($file_remote, $destino)){
            echo "Moved in server";
        }
        else
            echo "Not moved";

    }

}
?>
```

That works if I use it alone, but when I try to insert it into the code where I take all the post params from the form, then it doesn't work, and I don't know why.

I'm thinking about use 2 different forms, but upload a photo is required with the form, and then I was looking for some JS codes that allow me to send 2 forms with the same Submit button, but maybe is not a good idea.

Thanks!

Comment: Um, only one form can be submitted at a time unless they are being submitted to frames/new windows.

Comment: can you show your html, and the other code where you're inserting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t understand your question, but if you want get more params in the request to page, you can use:

Form:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formz" >
    Name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="name" /><br /><br />
    Email:<br />
    <input type="text" name="email" /><br /><br />
    Picture:<br />
    <input type="file" name="img" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="GO!" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //Get the vars
    $name  = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    //---


    $file = $_FILES["img"]["name"];
    $file_remote = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];


if ($file){
    if(strstr($file,".jpg")||strstr($file,".jpeg")||strstr($file,".png")){
        $destino = "/absolute/route/directory/".$file;
        if(move_uploaded_file($file_remote, $destino)){
            echo "Moved in server";
        }
        else
            echo "Not moved";

    }


    //Show up the values
    echo('Name: ' . $name);
    echo('Email: ' . $email);
    //---
}
```

You only need put the values on your database.

Comment: Thanks! I was doing that all time, but reading your answer I've noticed that I forgot to add the "enctype" as "multiform/form-data". Now it works correctly.